# Bootstrap tool tips look plain

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Am trying to get a tooltip that has more styling than the plain text that a tool tip normally has.

I see that a Twitter Bootstrap tooltip is black, white text, has an arrow, etc.

My tool tips look like this:

[image: plain tooltip]

I have read that to fix this I need to add this:

```
<script>
   $(function () { $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); });
</script>
```

I did that and it has no effect.

The only thing I could possibly think might be affecting it is that this is an Aurelia application and I am doing this in a `<template>`.

**Anything else I can be checking to see why this is not working?**

Code:

```
<template>
     <script src="myPathToJQuery/jquery@2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="myPathToBootstrap/twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
           data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="<b>Tooltip</b> <em>on </em> right">
        Tooltip on right
    </button>

    <script>
        $(function() { $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); });
    </script>
</template>
```

Comment: Are you sure Bootstrap's JS asset is loaded?

Comment: @iH8 - I added this to the top of the html (after <template>) -- `<script src="myPathToJQuery/jquery@2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="myPathToBootStrap/twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`  Would that load it?  (Still did not change it)

Comment: Yes this is weird! take this fiddle for example https://jsfiddle.net/mm6ck3dc/2/ it should have the black tooltip and it does not anymore, what has changed?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith you're having mixed content errors, try running that of `http`: http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ck3dc/2/

Comment: @iH8 you are right lol, something phishy is going on with my fiddles lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an [answer](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/233) from an Aurelia team member.  This is what he said:

Bootstrap's tooltip component requires javascript. Use a custom attribute to execute the tooltip javascript

```
import {customAttribute, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';

@customAttribute('bootstrap-tooltip')
@inject(Element)
export class BootstrapTooltip {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  bind() {
    $(this.element).tooltip();
  }

  unbind() {
    $(this.element).tooltip('destroy');
  }
}
```

Then on the element, add the bootstrap-tooltip attribute:

```
<require from="./bootstrap-tooltip"></require>

<input bootstrap-tooltip data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-title="bootstrap tooltip" title="html tooltip">
```

It works against the aurelia skeleton app.  (I will work it into my typescript app.)

Answer (score 1):

There is small mistake in your code

```
ata-placement="top"
```

You missed D letter from data-placement, your code should be:

```
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="<b>Tooltip</b> <em>on </em> right">
        Tooltip on right
    </button>
```

Instead of:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
       ata-placement="top" data-html="true" title="<b>Tooltip</b> <em>on </em> right">
    Tooltip on right
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  Alas, that is a typo in just the question.  As I was copying the code to the question, it did not fit without scrollbars.  So I tried to wrap it to a new line.  When I did that I lost the leading "d".  My actual code has the full `data-placement`.